# How to display square table for an unknown amount of numbers

Tags: java, arrays, output, primes

I'm writing a program that computes a sequence of prime number and then displays them in a table.

The programs asks the user to input 2 integers: the first one is the number with which the sequence starts and the second one is the amount of prime numbers to be found. Up to here, the program works perfectly.
The issue is that the prime numbers should be displayed in a "squarish" table, meaning that if possible, the table should be perfectly square. If that is not possible, then the number of rows and columns should not differ by more than 1.

Here is an example of what I've tried:

```
   int columns = 0;
   int rows = 0;
   int element = 0;

   rows = (int) Math.sqrt(numberOfPrimes);
   columns = (rows * rows) < numberOfPrimes ? rows + 1 : rows;

   if(numberOfPrimes%3 - 1.0 < 0.001)
   {
       columns = rows + 1;
       rows = rows + 1;
   }

   if (numberOfPrimes > 100)
   {
       columns = 10;
       if (rows * rows < numberOfPrimes)
       {
           rows = numberOfPrimes / 10;
       }

   }
   System.out.println(numberOfPrimes + " = [" + rows + "," + columns + "]");


   for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) 
   {
      for (int c = 0; c < columns; c++)
      {
          System.out.printf("%6s", primesArray[element] + "\t");
          if (element == primesArray.length - 1)
          {
              break;
          }
          element++;
      }
      System.out.println();
   }
```

The table is displayed properly for some inputs but not for others. I am aware that this code is incorrect but I have no idea of how to write the proper code to do this.
Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I updated the code to what I have now. The table does not work properly for odd numbers such as 33. It only prints 30 numbers and not the remaining 3. I need an extra row that prints those remaining numbers, even if that row is incomplete. 
I tried to solve this but I created an array out of bounds error.
Also, I added an if statement because if the number of primes is more than 100 then the table should have only 10 columns and will not be square.

EDIT 2: I managed to solve the problem and I've updated the code to show the solution. However, I had to use a break and my professor does not allow us to use breaks. Is there any other way for the loop to be exited once we reach the final element in the array?

Comment: I modified my answer to show how to exit the loop without a break.  Although I don't think there is anything wrong with a break statement.

Comment: I don't think so either but my professor won't let us use them cause he says it's bad practice. Anyway, the code works now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way

```
    int primeNumbersToBeFound = 33;

    int rows = (int) Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(primeNumbersToBeFound));
    int cols = rows;
    if (rows * (rows - 1) >= primeNumbersToBeFound) {
        cols--;
    }

    System.out.println(primeNumbersToBeFound + " = [" + rows + "," + cols + "]");
```

Then you can loop over rows and columns printing the primes.

```
    for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < cols && element < primesArray.length; c++, element++) {
            System.out.print(primesArray[element]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: It works perfectly. Thank you so much. I don't think I would've been able to figure it out on my own.

Comment: After further testing I've noticed an issue with the code. It works fine for numbers divisible by 2. However, if the number of primes is something like 33 it will only print 30 prime numbers and not the remaining 3. I need to add an extra row that displays the remaining 3 prime numbers even if the row is incomplete. My attempt at solving this caused an array out of bounds error.

Comment: I have modified the answer.